# Can I dump a Unicode string to an array of bytes?

Tags: python, unicode, byte

I'd like to dump a simple Unicode string into an array of bytes, so I can refer to each as an int. Is this possible?

I'm looking to take a string `u"Hello World"` and convert it into UTF-8 and something that looks like this: `

```
[0x01, 0x02, ..., 0x02]
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: What do you mean refer to each as an int?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question could mean two things: either encode the Unicode string using, say, UTF8 and getting a list of the resultant bytes, or getting a list of Unicode code points.

In the former case:

```
list_of_bytes = map(ord, my_unicode_string.encode('utf8'))
```

In the latter case:

```
list_of_code_points = map(ord, my_unicode_string)
```

Comment: Given that some (gosh, that's an understatement) unicode characters don't have code points in the range `[0..255]`, the former seems more likely.

Comment: The former will give you an encoded version of the values, so for the character `u'誠'` you'd get `[232, 170, 160]`, whereas the latter will give you the full Unicode point value (`8AA0 -> 35488`).  Depending on what @TK Kocheran wants to accomplish, both of these methods work pretty well.

Comment: I'm looking for the first case, and thanks! Is there a way I can map `hex()` to each of the values so I have them in hexadecimal strings in the array?

Comment: Yeah: use `lambda x: hex(ord(x))` instead of just `ord`.

Answer (score 13):

If you're looking for a Python [bytearray](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/functions.html#bytearray):

```
my_array = bytearray(u"hello, world", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: follow it with `output = []; for i in ba: output.add(hex(i)) ;; print ", ".join(output)`. For the win!

Comment: There's an even easier way to do that: `print ", ".join(map(hex, ba))`

Comment: A one-liner to print the byte string without the 0x separators: `return "".join(map(hex, bytearray(in_string, encoding="utf-8"))).replace('0x','')`